# Not able to boot from USB on Acer Aspire TC-895-UA92 Desktop, F12 not working (trying to install linux/ubuntu)

Tags: acer-aspire, liveusb, boot-manager

I want to install Linux/Ubuntu on this desktop but cannot boot from the USB to do so. I am not concerned about dual boot or partitions.

- The `Acer Aspire TC-895-UA92 Desktop` is not booting from the USB. The USB has been made into a bootable USB using `rufus` on windows by burning the 18.04 ubuntu iso image onto it.
- Starting the desktop again after shutting down, the bottom of the screen on start up says to push F12 for the boot menu and Del (delete key) for the BIOS. The key **F12** is pressed but no change in the boot start up of Windows occurs. No other key works for the boot menu, and only **Del** works to bring up the BIOS screen.
- From the BIOS there appears to be no option to enable F12 option as mentioned in [SU answer](https://superuser.com/a/874315/47618) or as displayed in [this YT video for another Acer computer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XobutFR9m10). I have looked repetitively for it and failed to find any reference to `F12` but there is an option for `Boot Menu` which should activate via F12 but does not function in my case.
- At the BIOS, the `Boot Options` tab, I changed the order of the `Boot Device` to be the `Removable Device` to be the `1st Boot Device`, and have the `HDD` `Windows Boot Manager` to become the `3rd Boot Device`.

After restarting multiple times, and using all options of F12-F1 and Esc only Del works bringing it back to BIOS setup or the Windows start.

Comment: How did you make the bootable usb?

Comment: @Moab, in the first point it says *The USB has been made into a bootable USB using rufus on windows by burning the 18.04 ubuntu iso image onto it.* does that need to be made more clear with more information?

Comment: There are lots of settings in rufus, which options did you choose?

Comment: @Moab, FAT32 with default clustersize

Comment: Some aspires have an enable F12 boot menu in the bios and must be enabled. Esc and F2 are also boot menu keys on some aspires.

Comment: @Moab, as point 3 mentions, this was not visible in the aspire I received. I looked everywhere for it in the BIOS. I did try every F1-F12 and Esc without it working. As the answers below say, the issue addressed by disabling the secure boot, and not using the **packaged keyboard** which required a toggle to use the function keys.

Comment: Try shift F12..........

Answer (score 0):

The desktop comes with a **keyboard** in the box of which the `Function keys` are **not working** without pressing them with the `Fn` key or `Alt`. So you cannot just press `F12`.

You can *use a different keyboard* where this is not a default and then use `F12` which will bring up the boot menu allowing you to choose the device to boot from when the order of the OS is after the USB or you can *press the Fn key with the function keys*.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Vass note about actually "pressing F12" when it needs a meta key pressed, please note you may need to disable secure boot.

Answer (score 0):

It has to be formatted as GPT and not MBR in order for an Acer 895 to recognize it.